# Sum involving $1F1$ and $2F2$ with exponential and factorial

Tags: calculus, special-functions, power-series

Is there any chance of computing the following sum? I have tried a lot of things, yet I didn't manage to get rid of the sum.. Is there any formula?

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {b^n {_1F_1}[n,1,\pi b c] {_2F_2}[{1,n},{n+1,n+1},b]} {2^nn!n}$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not familiar with $F_1$, $F_2$. Perhaps you could provide a link to their definition.

Comment: 2F2:
http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F2/02/

1F1:
http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/02/

Thank you for your interest